# Google OneTap in Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, google-identity

I'd like to implement Google OneTap in my Angular Universal app (that uses SSR). I'm using Angular 11, and the following script was working before converting the app to Angular Universal:

```
initGoogleOneTap() {
  const domain = window.location.hostname;
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: environment.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY,
    cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
    auto_select: true,
    state_cookie_domain: domain,
    callback: (response: any) => {
      this.oneTapLogIn(response.credential)
        .catch( (error) => {
          console.error('Error logging in with Google One Tap: ', error);
        });
    },
  });

  google.accounts.id.prompt( (notification: any) => {
    if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
      // try next provider if OneTap is not displayed or skipped
    }
  });
}
```

I am using `declare var google: any` at the top of the script.

The error I am getting is: `ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

First, load client library by putting this in your `index.html`

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Then, implement your component like this

```
declare var window: any;

ngOnInit() {
  window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: 'YOUR CLIENT ID',
    callback: this.handleGgOneTap.bind(this)
  });
  window.google.accounts.id.prompt();
}

handleGgOneTap(resp) {
  console.log('handleGgOneTap ', resp);
}
```

Comment: unable to access 'this' in callback function. getting 'this.functionName is not a function' error. unable to access component functions.